# Maven, running the demo app with java after demo script runs?

Tags: java, maven

Does anyone know how to run the demo app included with Maven installation?

I'm assuming it's a package?

If I remove `package com.mycompany.app` from the following, invoke `javac` then `java App`, then things work.  So I assume I'm trying to understand how to invoke main from the package.

`[~/src/java/demoapp/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app]$ vi App.java`

```
  1 package com.mycompany.app;
  2 
  3 /**
  4  * Hello world!
  5  *
  6  */
  7 public class App 
  8 {
  9     public static void main( String[] args )
 10     {
 11         System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
 12     }
 13 }
```

Comment: Can you try running `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.App"` in the project root?

Comment: @dan1st this ran main.  How do I invoke the application with java itself?  Is it in the target directory?

Comment: The point of Maven is that you don't do this. You run Maven, Maven finds/downloads all dependencies, runs javac, java and all the other stuff. But you could try running `java.com.mycompany.app.App` from the classpath root if you have no dependencies.

Comment: Thanks.  What option should I provide 'mvn' so java is invoked to run the program from there?  Also, to your suggestion, I try 'java target.classes.com.mycompany.app.App' and get 'Error: Could not find or load main class target.classes.com.mycompany.app.App; Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: target/classes/com/mycompany/app/App (wrong name: com/mycompany/app/App'  maybe because it's a package?

Comment: `target/classes` is the classpath root. You need to run it from there. Also, Maven does everything if you use `mvn exec:java` for you.

Comment: cd `target/classes` then `java com.mycompany.app.App` worked thanks!